# What is the source of Saraswati Stotram?

Tags: identification-request, shakti, saraswati, shaktism, translation

> श्वेतपद्मासना देवी श्वेतपुष्पोपशोभिता ।
> श्वेताम्बरधरा नित्या श्वेतगन्धानुलेपना ॥ १॥
> श्वेताक्षी शुक्लवस्त्रा च श्वेतचन्दनचर्चिता ।
> वरदा सिद्धगन्धर्वैरृषिभिः स्तूयते सदा ॥ २॥
> स्तोत्रेणानेन तां देवीं जगद्धात्रीं सरस्वतीम् ।
> ये स्मरन्ति त्रिकालेषु सर्वाविद्यां लभन्ति ते ॥ ३॥
> या देवी स्तूयते नित्यं ब्रह्मेन्द्रसुरकिन्नरैः ।
> सा ममैवास्तु जिह्वाग्रे पद्महस्ता सरस्वती ॥ ४॥

Saraswati Stotram is chanted in Pujas. You can listen to it [here](https://youtu.be/iOK_Hd_INZE). I want to know the source of this Stotra. I guess it may be from some Purana. Can anybody please mention the verse numbers and the primary sourcebook? Also, if possible, please provide the English translation.

Comment: The following site says it is from Padma Purana. Verse number is not provided. Not sure. https://stotram.co.in/saraswati-stotram-1/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a forum for 'authenticating' youtube videos. your question is best directed to the author of the youtube video